# jQuery Form Submit, with form validation, send email beforeSubmit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

Wondering if anyone can help me with this slight problem i'm having. 
I am using 2 plugins with jQuery.

1. http://jquery.malsup.com
2. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

And what i'm trying to do is find out if someone submit's my form, send me an email (or database entry) to see if they went to the next step.

This is my code that I have so far, and for some reason I can't get the beforeSubmit to work properly, and it must be just a simple mis-use of what I have.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
$(".validate2").validate({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
                $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", true);
                $(".formResponse").show();
                $(".formResponse").append("<img src='../images/icons/ajax-loader.gif' />");

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../classes/class.jQueryCallbacks.php?a=notifySignUpButton",
                    data: { 'name': $(".firstName").val() }
                });

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) 
        {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#formId").submit(function () {
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", true);
                    $(".formResponse").show();
                    $(".formResponse").append("<img src='../images/icons/ajax-loader.gif' />");

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../classes/class.jQueryCallbacks.php?a=notifySignUpButton",
                        data: { 'name': $(".firstName").val() }
                    });

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```